# "More" and "new" CTAs on table rows

Tags: interaction-design, tables, call-to-action

I am creating tables in an application that shows the last 5 or so recently modified or created items. I want to be able to show that there are more rows (when there are more rows) but I also want to add a call to action to create a new item.

I like having the create new as the last row, because it is like adding a new row but I also see the link for showing the rest of the rows there as well.  Which of these is best to use or is there another solution? The "see all" function is a new page of all the rows with additional filters (it does not just show them directly beneath the ones there.)

[image: widget tables]

Comment: I agree with @Celine which option is most frequently used by the user is it Add or See widgets?

Comment: Probably add but there are also tables elsewhere that need 'see all' that don't require an add button.

Answer (score 1):

What is the most frequent action the user will do on this page? What is the type of use you're looking to drive (create plenty of widgets or re-use existing ones)?

If the user creates a new widget quite often, then a large CTA for this feature is important. It could be the top row, instead of the bottom one.

If the user typically uses the application to browse the existing widgets and select one, then the large CTA should be Show all widgets.

Placing both actions at the same level visually risks to be confusing for the user.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on something similar, and from my understanding, **Add new widget** has to be a more prior action, as it's impact is higher, adding the new instance to the array, and **See all widgets** is a secondary action that changes the view, but not creating any new elements.

Here are the 2 possible options for this layout. The first has a static header and the **Add new widget** CTA, the second has an anchored Header + CTA panel. I would use the second one if adding the new widget is crucial and always needs to be accessible.
[image]